# Interceptor with tap from rxjs/operators does not get HttpEvent object. Works on post request but not get requests

Tags: angular, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have an HttpInterceptor whose purpose is to write and read some headers in each request and from its responses.
I use HttpClient
I use tap from rxjs to read the response headers
When I do a post request I get an HttpEvent object (prototype jf), but when I do a get request I get a javascript object with prototype Object and a property type of value 0
Don't know what I'm missing. Can anybody point me what I am doing wrong?
this is angular

```
Angular: 15.0.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1500.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.0.0
@angular-devkit/core            15.0.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.0.0
@schematics/angular             15.0.0
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.8.4
webpack                         5.75.0
```

This is the interceptor (the methods getCsrfHeader and getCsrf only return name of the header and value)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
  intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    console.log("Actualizando CSRF desde", req.url);

    return next.handle(req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set(this.userService.getCsrfHeader()!,this.userService.getCsrf()!),
    }))
    .pipe(
      tap( {next: (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        console.log("Procesando respuesta para actualizar CSRF por acceso a ", req.url, req.body);
        console.log("Respuesta recibida en tipo", event, event.constructor.name);
        if(event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log("Respuesta Http. Buscando cabecera XSRF: ",event.url, event.body);

          let _csrf = (event as HttpResponse<any>).headers.get(this.userService.getCsrfHeader()!);
          if( _csrf !==null && _csrf !== undefined ) {
            this.userService.setCsrf(_csrf);
            console.log("Actualizando csrf a ", event.url, _csrf);
          }
        }
      }, error: (error) => {
        console.error("Error: ", error.status, error.message, error);
      }
    }
    )
    );
  }
}
```

This is a working POST code

```
login() {
    this.userService.login(this.username!, this.password!, this.captcha!)
    .subscribe( res => {
      console.log("Resultado de login: ", res);
      if(res.error) {
        this.errorLogin = res.error;
        this.errorLoginMessage = res.errorMessage;
      } else {
        // redirigir a /
        this.errorLogin = res.error;
        this.errorLoginMessage = "";
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/inicio");
      }
    });
  }
```

The login method from the userService

```
  public login(username: string, password: string, captcha: string): Observable<LoginStatus> {
    console.log("Intentando ingreso a aplicación");
    let data = {
      username: username,
      password: password,
      captcha: captcha
    };

    return this.http.post<LoginStatus>(this.loginUrl, data).pipe(
      map( res => {
        console.log("Procesando resultado de login");
        if(res.error) {
          // generar aviso de error de login
        } else {
          console.log("Login exitoso. Dirigiendo a /inicio");
          this.router.navigateByUrl("/inicio");
          this.menuService.cargaMenu();
        }
        return res;
      })
    );

  }
```

And a non working GET request.

```
   cargaMenu(): void {
     console.log("Prepara carga de menu");
     this.http.get<Menu>(this.menuUrl).pipe( map( menuData => {
       console.log("procesando menu", menuData);
       this.extraeMenu(menuData);
       //return of(this._items);
     }), catchError(error => {
       console.error("Problema descargando el menu", error);
       return of(error);
     })
   ).subscribe( res => {
   //console.log("Resultado de menu", res, this._items);
   });
  }
```

The method does what it needs to do but the interceptor fails to read the response headers since its tap gets an object  like in this screen capture

[image]